# Electrical RL circuit problem

Tags: resistors, inductor, impedance, homework, reactance

[image]

So I am given

**u(t)=325sin(314t+90°)V**

**i(t)=14.14sin(314t+30°)A**

**I have to find the impedance Z∠θ, value for the resistor and inductor, inductive reactance**

Urms∠θ = 325/sqrt2 ∠90°

Irms∠θ = 14.14/sqrt2 ∠30°

Z∠θ = Urms∠θ / Irms∠θ =22.98∠60°

Irms=I

Irms= Urms/R

1/R= Irms/Urms = 707/16250

R= 22.98Ω **but that cant be right since Z=sqrt(R^2+XL^2) and that would mean XL is 0** 
XL=ωL=314L=...

L= XL/ω = XL/314...

Comment: For one thing, I think you're confusing yourself (and us) by converting to RMS, when you could just as well work with the peak values throughout the calculation. It's just a scale factor that cancels out in most of your equations.

Comment: Think about the line "Irms = Urms/R". What are the conditions that it applies to? Does this circuit satisfy them?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Irms= Urms/R

This is only true for a purely resistive load, where you have a resistor-inductor series load.

For the general case, you should be using

$$I_{rms}=\frac{U_{rms}}{Z}.$$

But you in fact already implicitly used this equation to find \$Z\$, so it's not going to give you any extra information than you already have.

But, since you already have \$Z\$, you do have what you need to find \$R\$ and \$X_L\$ very easily, since

$$Z=R+jX_L$$

Now what you need to work out is how to get this cartesian form of \$Z\$ from the polar form you have (\$Z=22.98\angle 60^\circ\$).

Comment: so Z=11.49+19.90j, R=11.49 AND jXL=19.90 ?

Comment: @GCODE2, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track by thinking in terms of phasors. It would probably help if you sketch the phasor diagram explicitly. Think of it in terms of the voltages around the loop:

- The current induces a voltage in the resistor that is always in-phase with the current, and proportional to the resistance. This is one of the short legs of a triangle.
- The current induces a voltage in the inductor that is always 90° out of phase with the current, and the magnitude is proportional to the inductive reactance. This is the other leg of the triangle.

You've been given the total voltage; this is the third side of the triangle — the vector sum of the other two legs. So, now you know two angles and one side of a right triangle; it should be straightforward to calculate the lengths of the other two sides, which are the two voltages described above. Everything else follows from that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that:

- $$\text{j}^2=-1\tag1$$
- $$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}=\text{R}\tag2$$
- $$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}=\text{j}\omega\text{L}\tag3$$
- $$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\tag4$$

Now, in your circuit we have:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}}+\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{L}}=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\tag5$$

The complex input voltage is given by:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=325\exp\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cdot\text{j}\right)=325\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)\tag6$$

Now, the complex input current (that is generated by the source) is given by:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}=\frac{325\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\tag7$$

So, we get for the time-representation:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\left(t\right)=\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|\cos\left(\omega t+\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\right)\tag8$$

Which will give:

- $$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right|=\left|\frac{325\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right|=\frac{\left|325\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)\right|}{\left|\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}=\frac{325}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\tag9$$
- $$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{325\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)}{\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right)=$$
  $$\arg\left(325\right)+\arg\left(\exp\left(0\cdot\text{j}\right)\right)-\arg\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)=$$
  $$0+0-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)\tag{10}$$

Now, we can set up a system of equations, in order to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\omega=314\\
\\\frac{325}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}=\frac{707}{50}\\
\\
-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}}\right)=\frac{30\pi}{180}-\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}\space\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\space\begin{cases}
\text{R}=\frac{8125}{707}\approx11.4922\space\Omega\\
\\
\text{L}=\frac{8125\sqrt{3}}{221998}\approx0.0634\space\text{H}
\end{cases}\tag{11}
$$

So:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}=\frac{8125}{707}+\text{j}\cdot314\cdot\frac{8125\sqrt{3}}{221998}=$$
$$\frac{8125}{707}+\text{j}\cdot\frac{8125\sqrt{3}}{707}=\frac{16250}{707}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot\text{j}\right)=$$
$$\frac{16250}{707}\angle60^\circ\approx22.9844\angle60^\circ\tag{12}$$